# Cannot seem to add internal testers with existing iTunes Connect accounts

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to add internal beta testers to my app. The app is still in development, so I do not wish to submit the app for review for external testers. It seems the only way I can add an internal tester is if I add them as a new iTunes Connect User. When I try to though, I cannot because the Apple ID (email) of the person I want to invite already has an iTunes Connect account. Is there any way I can add people who already have Connect accounts as internal testers?

Comment: Now it's possible to associate same email with different iTunes Connect organisations. Then it's possible to manage with same Apple ID different apps of different organisations! Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After emailing Apple Support about this, I received an email saying this:

> If a person's Apple ID is already associated with another iTunes
>   Connect organization, the user needs to provide a distinct email
>   address that can be associated with the new organization; iTunes
>   Connect creates an additional Apple ID for the user.

I think it seems odd that Apple would require someone with an existing IC account to create another one just to be an admin on another user's organization, but this did work for me.

I used another one of my emails and created a new Apple ID when adding myself as another admin into the group. When I finally received a beta tester invite through that email, I was also able to install and use the app through my previous Apple ID.

Comment: Now it's possible to associate same email with different iTunes Connect organisations. Then it's possible to manage with same Apple ID different apps of different organisations! Thanks Apple!

Comment: I ran into this today. Couldn't add an existing AppleID as a "Developer", but it worked as an "Admin". Seems like `sudo` even solves problems with iTunes Connect 

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "+" sign to add the same email to your desired iTunes Connect Account.

If the email is someone@gmail.com, you can add it like this: someone+0@gmail.com

The system ignores the "+" sign and any character after that, it works like a charm but you have to use the altered email for the login.

Comment: I believe the + sign is gmail only feature. I don't see the OP mentioning gmail anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem like Leo. I had to add another email id of for same user and then add it to `Internal Testers`/`External Testers` list which worked well for me.

But, it feels strange that why an already iTunes user be restricted to be part of another org as well, provided he contribute well to app quality!